# Remove/change a resource ID

Tags: android

So I'm quite new to Android development. The declaration for Team 1 in R.java here

```
public static final class id {
    public static final int All=0x7f080000;
    public static final int CS_GO=0x7f080001;
    public static final int Dota_2=0x7f080002;
    public static final int Dual=0x7f080003;
    public static final int General=0x7f080004;
    public static final int Single=0x7f080005;
    public static final int Team 1=0x7f080006;
    public static final int Team_2=0x7f080007;
    public static final int Time=0x7f080008;
    public static final int Tournament=0x7f080009;
    public static final int Triplet=0x7f08000a;
```

is causing this error.

```
C:\Users\KHOI PHAM\AndroidStudioProjects\a1\app\build\generated\source\r\debug\com\example\khoipham\a1\R.java
Error:(2461, 33) error: ';' expected
```

I suspect the only way to fix this error is to remove the id "Team 1" entirely, but I don't know how to. Would anyone be able to assist me? TIA.

Comment: You forgot an underscore (it should be `Team_1`)...I'm surprised your IDE didn't highlight this.

Comment: You are not adding the semi colon `";"` at the end of a statement hence the error. Review your code closely. AS points out the error.

Comment: You're **not supposed** to touch R.java! Leave it alone!!

Comment: I know I cannot modify R.java for this, which is why I'm asking if there is a way.

Comment: Fix it in the XML file where you've defined that ID. Then clean/rebuild.

Comment: I already changed it to a different ID in that XML file but this ID still exists for some reason

Answer (score 2):

**There is a space between words `Team 1` .**

The best way is modified that you change the `Team 1`id in defining places.

Because you have problem is this .

```
public static final int Team 1=0x7f080006;
```

change to

```
android:id="@+id/Team_1"
```

Comment: R.java cannot be modified.

Comment: If I change it like you said, after I build the project "Team 1" will show up again

Comment: I edited it .You can modified that you change the Team 1id in defining places.@KhôiPhạm

Comment: After you change the id ,you can build your project .

Answer (score 0):

`R.java` is auto-generated by the Android Studio, you can change it but it's in vain because Android Studio will auto-generated all the variables whenever there's a change in your XML id and replace all the change you have done.

The error is usually happened because you have a wrong id or name in your XML. You need to find the `Team 1` in your XML file then change it to a valid one. Each id should not using a space.

Comment: I already changed the ID of that object to a new one but the old Team 1 ID doesn't go away

Comment: You should change the id in the XML which is containing `Team 1`. Use find tool in Android Studio.

Comment: I did and the only Team 1 left in the project is in the R.java file

Comment: What is the `Team 1`  for? Probably an image?

Comment: Just an EditText

Comment: Change the id then rebuild

Comment: I did that too. Even tried to delete the whole .xml with that id but it still pop up for some reason

Comment: Looks like you've edited/deleted the file in the wrong place. You should change the file in src/main/res/ folder not in the debug folder.

Comment: I checked it was in res

Comment: recheck all of your files in your `/src/main/res`. There should be something there.